# How to iterate over an int array in GORM

Tags: go, go-gorm, go-gin

In the `Params` model I have an array of int `Cat_id`

I make a request: `localhost:8080/products/?cat_id=1,2`
And I want to display multiple products from these two categories. How can I parsely build my query?
My func:

```
func GetAllIproducts(q *models.Products, pagination *models.Params) (*[]models.Products, error) {
    var prod []models.Products
    offset := (pagination.Page - 1) * pagination.Limit
    result := config.DB.Model(&models.Products{}).Where(q).Where("cat_id=?", pagination.Cat_id).Limit(pagination.Limit).Offset(offset).Find(&prod) //Problem is here
    if result.Error != nil {
        msg := result.Error
        return nil, msg
    }
    return &prod, nil
}
```

When i use `Debug` i got this:
`SELECT * FROM "products" WHERE cat_id=(1,2) AND "products"."deleted_at" IS NULL`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the `cat_id` is an integer (lets assume `int64`), you could these two things:

1. Convert `pagination.Cat_id` string to an `[]int64` slice (lets call this variable `catIDs` of type `[]int64`) to get a slice with separated `int64` elements.
2. Change your `Where` clause to something like this:

   ```
    result := config.DB.Model(&models.Products{}).Where(q).Where("cat_id IN (?)", catIDs).Limit(pagination.Limit).Offset(offset).Find(&prod)
   ```